# C# Mathematical Functions

Tags: c#, math, formulas

like other programmers I am also new to the world of programming and I want to live in this world and achieve rewards using your help. So, I have to use a mathematical function in Cmath.

The function is

```
z1 = Sin2α + sin5α - Sin3α / cosα+1-2sin^2(2α)
z2= √x^3 + 3 / x^3 - 3
```

My results so far...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine ("First Program");
            Console.WriteLine ("Enter an integer");
            int x;
            x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine ("x = " + x);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid number");



            //Solving the functions
            double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Read the angle in degrees
            a = a / 180 * Math.PI;
            double z = (Math.Cos(a)) + (Math.Cos(2 * a)) + (Math.Sin(6 * a)) + (Math.Cos(7 * a));
            z = (x * x) + (2(x)) - (3) + (x + 1) * Math.Sqrt(x * x - 9) / (x * x) - (2(x)) - (3) + (x - 1) * Math.Sqrt(x * x - 9);




            Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Comment: All math-related functions are in `System.Math` class, hence `f = Math.Sin(2)...`

Comment: That function won't compile.  There's no "2Sin * Sin2".  Makes no sense at all.

Comment: Did a Google search of "C# math functions" really turn up nothing?

Comment: You really need to read some beginner level book first. In `c#` you don't write *shorthand* `2Sin`, but use *operators* : `2 * Sin(...)`. You need to understand what are functions and parameters, what are namespaces and variables to be able to write in correct syntax something like `Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 3))`.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, the formulas can be implemented as follows; However, it is not totally clear if the terms are bracketed as desired.

```
double z1(double alpha)
{
    return Math.Sin(2.0f * alpha)
         + Math.Sin(5.0f * alpha)
         - Math.Sin(3.0f * alpha) / Math.Cos(alpha)
                                    + 1.0f + 2.0f * Math.Sin(2.0f * alpha);
}

double z2(double x)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(x * x * x) + 3.0f / (x * x * x) - 3.0f;
}
```

Comment: Please look again at the question now.